# mysql in only return distinct?

Tags: mysql

```
select sum(price) 
from product 
where id in (select productid 
             from orders where status!=0 
             and userid=1)
```

if my returned productid = (1,2,2)

the sum will only be sum of 1 and 2 instead of sum of 1,2,and2

i tried

```
select sum(price) from product where id in (1,2,2)
```

same result, how do i get indistinct sum?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUM(p.price)
FROM product AS p
    LEFT JOIN orders AS o
        ON p.id = o.productid
WHERE o.productid IS NOT NULL
    AND o.status <> 0
    AND o.userid = 1
```

Comment: you might want to validate the answer if it is soo awesomeness